# on click color of div and css both changes separately

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have one `div`. Inside that `div` I have an `a` tag and inside that `a` tag I have another `div`. I am adding a CSS class using `ng-class` but when I click on the div and on the text of the div it gets colored separately. If I click on the div in non text area the whole div gets colored. I want the whole div colored even when I click on text on that div

Thanks in advance

code:-

```
<div class="menu_links" ng-repeat="menu in links.data" ng-if="menu.display_menu==1" namemenu="{{menu.menu_name}}" >
    <a ng-if="menu.menu_id != 1" class="speedlinks left skyBlueBack marRt15px marBot10px text-center">
        <div class="data linkBox" ng-click="toggle($event)" valSet_link_name="{{menu.menu_name}}" valSet_link="{{menu.menu_link}}" valset_display="{{menu.display_menu}}" ng-class="{active: menu.menu_link == currSpeedLink}">
            <b>{{menu.menu_name}}</b>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put a `DIV` inside an `A`. So before doing anything else change that to a `SPAN` and see if it fixes it (I did not read your code).

Comment: no man stil the text is getting colored separately

Comment: Sorry, I've never used angularjs so it's way too hard for me to read your code. Maybe someone else will help. Or you could post the generated `HTML/Javascript/CSS`, but I don't know if that will help you.

Comment: ariel how can i let u know my output

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you need someone who knows `AngularJS` to help you.

Comment: @Ariel `You can't put a DIV inside an A` [You can in HTML5](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links), not that I particularly feel that people should.

Comment: @MLeFevre I know, but not all browsers support it yet, so for right now don't.

Comment: Try putting your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ - there is an option for angularJS. I can't promise anything, but maybe you will get a reply once the code is easier to see.

Comment: @user3659806: This is one messy piece of Angular code :) There is too little information to diagnose the problem (even to understand what the problem is) and there are too many irrelevant bits that make it even harder. Try creating an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** (a fiddle would be even better) !